Issues deploying a basic next.js app to Google Cloud platform (Cloud Run)
I am attempting to deploy my basic next.js app (code here) to google cloud run using a basic CI/CD pipeline. I have a dockerfile that works fine locally, and builds on GCP:
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm ci

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
RUN npm run build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

ENV PORT=${PORT:-8080}
EXPOSE ${PORT}

#CMD ["node", "server.js"] <- I have tried this as well
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

The issue is that that is all it does. Building is the only step (if i were to do this through firebase there would be multiple steps) and after completing the build nothing seems to actually deploy. And it just has the placeholder text: app url. I have set my (IAM) permissions correctly (as far as I can tell). What am I missing?
Please feel free to comment on any other relevant/useful information I could give.
Also: I know  my dockerfile uses a lowercase d instead of an uppercase D, but I have it set correctly in GCP, and it clearly reads the dockerfile and does its contents

Edit:

I  have added my trigger file as an image. Is my issue that I need a cloudbuild.yaml file?

Your question is unclear but I suspect you're expectation is that Cloud Build will deploy to Cloud Run too. This is possible but evidently, it's not what you've configured Cloud Build to do since it's only building the container for you. See the documentation for an example of using Deploying to Cloud Run using Cloud Build

Your code here reference is invalid. You may have intended this

@DazWilkin 2 things:

the link you shared has broken CSS and is hard to read, but ill try to figure it out.
ive watched several youtube tutorials on this and there was never a clear distinction made between the two. I had followed several to the letter and this has been the end result. My main problem with consulting the docs is that I didn't know what the problem is to even look for in the docs. Thank you for bringing the distinction to my attention. Im very new to google cloud platform deployments, and you do all the steps in the cloud run tab so i assumed it would run what it built


It's confusing and Google's service names don't really help. You can use Cloud Build to deploy (!) to e.g. Cloud Run but it requires additional steps that are described in the documentation that I referenced. Cloud Build is essentially a powerful tool that allows you to run sequences of steps in the cloud with each step being the result of running a container. So, you can do many things with Cloud Build not only building containers.

Im trying to read the docks now. Would it be easier to use a different service like app engine? I was using cloud run because i was under the impression that it would be cheaper/better free tier (even if only slightly).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You just need to add cloud run deployment to a build step in your cloud build job.
Here's a sample cloudbuild yaml file you could use as a starting point:
steps:
  - id: Build
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
        docker build -t gcr.io......<your tag here> && \
        docker push -t gcr.io......<your tag here> 

  - id: Deploy to Cloud Run
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
        gcloud run deploy myNextJSApp \
        --image <your gcr.io tag from the build step> \
        --region australia-southeast2 \
        --platform managed \
        --allow-unauthenticated

